# The proofs in W.M.Gorman "Community preference fields''

Tags: macroeconomics, aggregate-demand

I am reading W.M.Gorman ["Community preference fields''](https://academic.oup.com/book/37280/chapter-abstract/330901492?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

However, many of the proofs are omitted or only in outlines.
Do you know some other helpful references?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any specific result you are interested in?

Comment: I'm interested in the existence of a representative consumer, and its conditions.

Comment: What makes Gorman's result a bit complicated is that it is a local theory of aggregation. If we know that the consumption set is $\mathbb{R}^l_+$, then we know what the expenditure at an income level of $0$ is, namely $0$. In that case, the result reduces to one of Antonelli from 1886. You can find the simple proof in the chapter by Shafer and Sonnenschein in Volume 2 of the Handbook of Mathematical Economics.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will read it!